# restore single mysql table from database sql file

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, centos

I have mysql table named **session** i want to restore it from **smith.sql** file to database name **smith**

From my linux box i run mysql command to restore the whole databae

```
# mysql smith < smith.sql
```

How could i restore session table only ?

Comment: You will need to select the part of smith.sql which creates and restores the session table only.
It would help if you post smith.sql

Answer (score -2):

start->XAMPP control panel

then open your browser window --> type phpmyadmin
select your database --> click on create table button
then enter table name --> enter single default column name like id --> select int datatype -->
then click save button.

now your table created sucessfully.

now do u want to restore old table data to new table data.

select newly created table --> then click on import button top of the screen --> browse your single table sql file --> select format option sql --> then click GO button.

thats it now u have all u r old table data in u r new table

[enter link description here](http://www.vaaah.com)

Comment: he doesn't have the single table sql file, that is what the whole question is about